# Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable for Apache POI workbook

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsx

I have a code which is working completely fine in one system for the below code and in another system I am getting compilation error. Both systems have same jars and Java 8 for the workspace.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
.
.
.
final FileInputStream xlFile = new FileInputStream(filePath + fileName);
xlWBook = StreamingReader.builder()
                        .rowCacheSize(100) // number of rows to keep in memory (defaults to 10)
                        .bufferSize(2048) // buffer size to use when reading InputStream to file (defaults to 1024)
                        .open(xlFile);
for (final Sheet sheet : xlWBook){
    System.out.println(sheet.getSheetName());
    for (final Row r : sheet) {
.
.
.
```

The compilation issue it shows in the 2nd system is at the below line on xlWBook
Error: **Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable:**

```
for (final Sheet sheet : xlWBook){
```

Any idea what might cause this? Jars for the workspace [image]

Comment: If this is a compilation error then you may have to check if the dependencies are loaded correctly or not. I don't see any other reason why it shouldn't work on a different machine apart from the build path issue.

Comment: hose are pretty old versions, what happens when you upgrade?